# Insert Data From DataGridView to Database Sql Server ( VB)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gridview, datagridview

I got 2 datagridviews in my form. Both gridview display data from database  local db. My current problem now is im trying to insert data from both gridview into the server database but i only managed to insert only 1 gridview. The second gridview didnt insert anything to the server database.

Here is my current code :

```
     Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

            GetProcess_A()
            GetProcess_B()

            InsertProcess_A()
            InsertProcess_B()

        End Sub

     Private Sub GetProcess_A()

            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT TID,TDESC,TPCNAME,MOD_DATE,SYNC_FLG FROM dbo.ZPA_TERMINAL where SYNC_FLG = 0", LocalDB)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Using dt As New DataTable()
                        sda.Fill(dt)
                        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

        End Sub

        Private Sub InsertProcess_A()

            Dim command As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.ZPAS_TERMINAL (TID, TDESC, TPCNAME, MOD_DATE) VALUES (@TID, @TDESC, @TPCNAME, @MOD_DATE)"

            command.Parameters.Add("@TID", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            command.Parameters.Add("@TDESC", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            command.Parameters.Add("@TPCNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            command.Parameters.Add("@MOD_DATE", SqlDbType.VarChar)

            ServerDB.Open()
            command.Connection = ServerDB

            For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                command.Parameters(0).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
                command.Parameters(1).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                command.Parameters(2).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
                command.Parameters(3).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next

            ServerDB.Close()

    End Sub

 Private Sub GetProcess_B()



        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT  (SELECT TID FROM dbo.ZPA_TERMINAL) AS TID,PGRP,PGRP_NAME,ACTIVE_FLAG,SYNC_FLG FROM SQLIOT.dbo.ZPA_PROCGRP WHERE SYNC_FLG = 0", LocalDB)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using


    End Sub


    Private Sub InsertProcess_B()

        Dim command As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.ZPAS_PROCGRP (TID, PGRP, PGRP_NAME, ACTIVE_FLAG) VALUES (@TID, @PGRP, @PGRP_NAME, @ACTIVE_FLAG)"

        command.Parameters.Add("@TID", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        command.Parameters.Add("@PGRP", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        command.Parameters.Add("@PGRP_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        command.Parameters.Add("@ACTIVE_FLAG", SqlDbType.VarChar)

        ServerDB.Open()
        command.Connection = ServerDB

        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1
            command.Parameters(0).Value = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            command.Parameters(1).Value = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
            command.Parameters(2).Value = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
            command.Parameters(3).Value = DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next

        ServerDB.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this the correct table name dbo.ZPAS_PROCGRP or this dbo.ZPA_PROCGRP?

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b both are different table. ZPAS for server DB while ZPA is from local DB. Im using 2 different server.

Comment: You should not be calling `ExecuteNonQuery`. You are using a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` and binding that to the grid. Use the same data adapter to save the changes back to the database from that `DataTable`. Just as `Fill` retrieves data, so `Update` saves changes. See [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases) for examples.

Comment: Note that the fact that the data is going to a different table than it's coming from doesn't actually matter. You can still use a data adapter, either the same one or a different one, to save the data. One thing to note is that all your retrieved rows will have a `RowState` of `Unchanged` by default, so won;t be insertable by default. If you want all the retrieved rows to be inserted to the other table then you can set `AcceptChangesOnFill` to `False` for the first data adapter. All the `RowState` values will then be `Added` and the rows will be ready to insert.

Comment: [Here is an example app in VB.Net](https://contrivedexample.com/2015/03/14/a-basic-example-of-crud-with-datagridview-in-vb-net/).